# Need to change URL in batch file after a timeout

Tags: google-chrome, batch-file, url

Very new to batch files/scripts etc, and I need a little help with a basic script I am working on. I've made a script that opens Chrome and goes to a website, and after 15 seconds, it opens a new tab and goes to a different page on that site. I would like it to re-use the same tab, but change the URL after the 15 seconds. Then, after the sequence I'd like Chrome to close.

I've tried searching for 'changing url in batch files', and experimented with things such as leaving out 'start chrome.exe' etc, but I've been getting nowhere for the last 3 hours, so thought I would reach out for help. Ideally, I'd like to keep it all within the batch file, rather than trying to use sendkeys/hotkeys etc.

Thanks in advance (code should be below)

P.S. If I am approaching this from the complete wrong angle, please let me know and point me in the right direction :)

```
@echo off
start chrome.exe --new-window www.domainname.com/
timeout /t 15
start chrome.exe www.domainname.com/about-us/
timeout /t 15
start chrome.exe www.domainname.com/gallery/
timeout /t 15
start chrome.exe www.domainname.com/contact-us/
timeout /t 15
close chrome.exe
exit
```

Comment: I have two questions. Does it have to be a batch script ? Does it **really** have to be a batch script ?

Comment: No, I guess not. I'm using a batch as it seemed the easiest for me to learn for what I need, AND, I can have a simple icon on desktop I can double-click :)
If it wasn't batch, what other alternatives/options are there?

Comment: @JusticeEmpire Many options are their, you name it, powershell, python , autoit they all have these functions. And most importantly, after you are doone they will just work like your `I can have a simple icon on desktop I can double-click`

Comment: @Mr.Helpy Thanks, I gathered there would be a million and 1 ways to do something like this. I have played with python before, so might give it a go again. Are you saying that I can't do what I am trying to achieve within a basic batch?

Comment: @JusticeEmpire Actually I don't know, I haven't seen anything like this but maybe you could find what you are looking for if you give google a try again. It's just that I don't like to do other's homework :D

Comment: @Mr.Helpy I have given google a good try, and haven't found the answer I'm looking for, hence why I am posting here. Loads of answers about creating multiple URLs etc, but nothing about changing the URL within the browswer :(

Comment: @JusticeEmpire BTW, I recommend sticking with python. You can do loads of stuff with it.